# How would you refer to "flats and drum(ette)s" in Spanish when talking about chicken wings?

Tags: traducción, comida

How would you refer to "flats and drum(ette)s" in Spanish when talking about chicken wings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Punta, alón y blanqueta

**Blanqueta, primera falange del Ala**

> La primera falange del ala de pollo es la más carnosa y es la que está situada más cerca de la pechuga.

- The first phalanx of the chicken wing is the meatiest and is the
  one located closest to the breast.

**Alón, segunda falange del Ala**

> La segunda falange del ala de pollo no contiene mucha carne, pero es generalmente más jugosa que el resto de las partes del ala.

- The second joint of the chicken wing does not contain much meat, but it's generally juicier than the rest of the wing parts.

**Punta, tercera falange del Ala**

> Y la tercera falange del ala de pollo es la menos carnosa, acabada en punta, que además de freír o asar, se emplea también para caldos.

- And the third phalanx of the chicken wing is the least fleshy, ending in a point, which in addition to frying or roasting, is also used for broths.

<sub>*Source [polleriasomolinos.com](https://polleriasomolinos.com/partes-del-pollo/)*</sub>

Although I must add that what here is called *blanquette* is popularly known as **muslito de ala** (wing drumstick).

[image]

<sub>*Image source [lacocinademjsalla](https://lacocinademjsalla.blogspot.com/2021/08/alitas-de-pollo-al-horno-al-estilo.html)*</sub>